# Preventing Showdown from modifying text between some delimiters

Tags: javascript, parsing, markdown, showdown, katex

Is there any way I can stop Showdown from parsing text in between some delimiters (`$` and `$$` in this case) so that it doesn't interpret my LaTeX code as markdown? If not, is there any other way of getting the two to work together? 
At the moment I am simply passing the input to Showdown and then giving that to Katex to interpret, which often results in Showdown inserting html tags in my LaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this `showdown-katex` extension? I can not vouch for its quality, but it fits your use case:

https://obedm503.github.io/showdown-katex/

For additional clues, there is this StackExchange answer describing how the Math StackExchange site allows LaTeX and markdown input: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9654

> The solution implemented on StackExchange is to preprocess user input by a third script (about 130 lines, named `mathjax-editing.js`) which escapes the text within $...$ or $$...$$ from Markdown. This way, formulas go intact through Markdown processing, and eventually get handled by MathJax.